# How I can show an dummy Arrow when I hover over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which mainly shows 4 Divs and each `Div` contains an image + text which displays underneath the image, here is my code:

```
<div style="float: left;margin-left:9px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="*****.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px"><a target="_blank" href="****">*****</a></span>
</div>
<div style="float: left;margin-left:9px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="*****.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px"><a target="_blank" href="****">*****</a></span>
</div>
<div style="float: left;margin-left:9px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="*****.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px"><a target="_blank" href="****">*****</a></span>
</div>
<div style="float: left;margin-left:9px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="*****.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px"><a target="_blank" href="****">*****</a></span>
</div>
```

the result will be as follows:

[image]

I want to make it so that when the user hovers over the last Div, it shows an arrow ">" on the image itself to mimic as if the user can show the next 4 items. Can anyone give advice on how I can implement this? At this stage, I just need to add a dummy arrow, nothing else.

now inside my last Div i added a class named `class='profile-image'`:-

```
<div  class="profile-image" style="float: left;margin-left:9px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="*****.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px"><a target="_blank" href="****">*****</a></span>
</div>
```

and then i defined the following css:-

```
.profile-image:hover .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent url('/Resources/xt.png') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but this did not have any effect...

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your CSS?

Comment: Use js carousel, each of slide will have your choice of four div and images? For showing and hiding arrow, you can write jQuery code, I.e. $("next").show(); , $("next").hide();

Comment: @AdamMcquiff see my edit, i provided the css i am using

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap all of your divs in a 'master' div (you could just give this a class of .master) then you will be able to use '[last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)' inside this class to target the last div that is inside it.

In the 'last-child' you can use [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) to allow you to display an image of an arrow when you hover over it. You could just add the arrow as a background image on the div and make this have 'visibility: visible;' or 'opacity: 1;' when it has an active hover state.

I hope this helps a bit :)

(edit: I would look to do this in a style sheet rather than inline styling)